# Select differentiating records from two tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with a field called `Date`. I want to select only the dates of `Table1` that are diferent from `Table2`.

In this case, the result would be 4 and 5.

```
Table1     Table2     Result
Date       Date       Date
1          1          4
2          2          5
3          3
4
5
```

Comment: How are they different?

Comment: @Paul - 2 and 3 does not make sense. Do you want records that are in both tables? (then 1, 2, 3 should be the result). Or do you want records that are not in one of the tables? (then 4,5 should be the result).

Comment: I made a mistake sorry, but now its correct xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question you want to select from `Table1` the rows that are not in `Table2` as well. Here is how you would do that:

```
SELECT Date FROM Table1 WHERE Date not in (SELECT Date FROM Table2)
```